# Show a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$ has no interior points.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Show a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$ has no interior points.  By $\mathbb{R}^3$ I mean euclidean space.

How to do this in a rigorous way?

Comment: What have you tried? What is the definition of an interior point being used here?

Comment: @Max There exists some ball within the set.  I tried setting it up algebraically i.e. $ax+by+cz=d$ and using arbitrary ball $x^2+y^2+z^2 < r$.

Comment: @helios321: Let $B$ be an open ball centred at a point $p$ in the plane. The line normal to the plane at $p$ contains points of $B$ that are not in the plane.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Yeah, but is there a way to express exactly that algebraically?

Comment: @helios321: It’s a little messy but possible. The plane $ax+by+cz=d$ has a normal vector $\langle a,b,c\rangle$, so adding a sufficiently small multiple of that to a point in the plane will do the trick.

Comment: I would first argue that you may assume without a loss of generality that your plane is $\{(x,y,z):z=0\}$, since this is the case up to some linear automorphism (which is a homeomorphism). And then it's a little less messy to prove this rigorously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $ax+by+cz=d$ plane. Without loss of generality assume that $c\neq 0$ (note that one of $a,b,c$ has to be nonzero in order for that to be a plane).

Take a point $(x,y,z)$ belonging to the plane. It is enough to show that for any $\epsilon>0$ the open ball $B=B((x,y,z),\epsilon)$ is not contained in the plane. Indeed, consider $(x,y,z+\epsilon)$ which belongs to $B$, but

$$ax+by+c(z+\epsilon)=ax+by+cz+c\epsilon=d+c\epsilon$$

and $d+c\epsilon\neq d$ because both $c\neq 0$ and $\epsilon\neq 0$. Thus $(x,y,z+\epsilon)$ does not belong to the plane. Which completes the proof. $\Box$

Note that similar reasoning can be easily generalized to any $\mathbb{R}^n$ and a subspace of the form $\sum_{i=1}^n a_ix_i=b$ for a fixed non-zero vector $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$. And thus to any affine subspace of dimension $<n$.